# What is a converting constructor in C++ ? What is it for?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

I have heard that C++ has something called "conversion constructors" or "converting constructors".  What are these, and what are they for?  I saw it mentioned with regards to this code:

```
class MyClass
{
  public:
     int a, b;
     MyClass( int i ) {}
}

 int main()
{
    MyClass M = 1 ;
}
```

Comment: Jeopardy! Host: Section §12.3.1 of both C++03 and C++11 standard describes this kind of constructor.  Contestant: What is a converting constructor? Stackoverflow Host: Wrong, the reply must be in the form of a real question.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The definition for a *converting constructor* is different between C++03 and C++11. In both cases it must be a non-`explicit` constructor (otherwise it wouldn't be involved in implicit conversions), but for C++03 it must also be callable with a single argument. That is:

```
struct foo
{
  foo(int x);              // 1
  foo(char* s, int x = 0); // 2
  foo(float f, int x);     // 3
  explicit foo(char x);    // 4
};
```

Constructors 1 and 2 are both converting constructors in C++03 and C++11. Constructor 3, which must take two arguments, is only a converting constructor in C++11. The last, constructor 4, is not a converting constructor because it is `explicit`.

- **C++03**: §12.3.1

  > A constructor declared without the *function-specifier* `explicit` that can be called with a single parameter specifies a conversion from the type of its first parameter to the type of its class. Such a constructor is called a converting constructor.
- **C++11**: §12.3.1

  > A constructor declared without the *function-specifier* `explicit` specifies a conversion from the types of its parameters to the type of its class. Such a constructor is called a converting constructor.

Why are constructors with more than a single parameter considered to be converting constructors in C++11? That is because the new standard provides us with some handy syntax for passing arguments and returning values using *braced-init-lists*. Consider the following example:

```
foo bar(foo f)
{
  return {1.0f, 5};
}
```

The ability to specify the return value as a *braced-init-list* is considered to be a conversion. This uses the converting constructor for `foo` that takes a `float` and an `int`. In addition, we can call this function by doing `bar({2.5f, 10})`. This is also a conversion. Since they are conversions, it makes sense for the constructors they use to be *converting constructors*.

It is important to note, therefore, that making the constructor of `foo` which takes a `float` and an `int` have the `explicit` function specifier would stop the above code from compiling. The above new syntax can only be used if there is a converting constructor available to do the job.

- **C++11**: §6.6.3:

  > A `return` statement with a *braced-init-list* initializes the object or reference to be returned from the function by copy-list-initialization (8.5.4) from the specified initializer list.

  §8.5:

  > The initialization that occurs [...] in argument passing [...] is called copy-initialization.

  §12.3.1:

  > An explicit constructor constructs objects just like non-explicit constructors, but does so only where the direct-initialization syntax (8.5) or where casts (5.2.9, 5.4) are explicitly used.

Answer (score 24):

**Converting implicitly with converting constructor**

Let's make the example in the question more complex

```
class MyClass
{
  public:
     int a, b;
     MyClass( int i ) {}
     MyClass( const char* n, int k = 0 ) {}
     MyClass( MyClass& obj ) {}
}
```

First two constructors are converting constructors. The third one is a copy constructor, and as such it is another converting constructor.

A converting constructor enables implicit conversion from argument type to the constructor type. Here, the first constructor enables conversion from an `int` to an object of class `MyClass`. Second constructor enables conversion from an string to an object of class `MyClass`. And third... from an object of class `MyClass` to an object of class `MyClass` !

To be a converting constructor, constructor must have single argument (in the second one, second argument has one default value) and be declared without keyword `explicit`.

Then, initialization in main can look like this:

```
int main()
{
    MyClass M = 1 ;
    // which is an alternative to
    MyClass M = MyClass(1) ;

    MyClass M = "super" ;
    // which is an alternative to
    MyClass M = MyClass("super", 0) ;
    // or
    MyClass M = MyClass("super") ;
}
```

**Explicit keyword and constructors**

Now, what if we had used the `explicit` keyword ?

```
class MyClass
{
  public:
     int a, b;
     explicit MyClass( int i ) {}
}
```

Then, compiler would not accept

```
   int main()
    {
        MyClass M = 1 ;
    }
```

since this is implicit conversion. Instead, have to write

```
   int main()
    {
        MyClass M(1) ;
        MyClass M = MyClass(1) ;
        MyClass* M = new MyClass(1) ;
        MyClass M = (MyClass)1;
        MyClass M = static_cast<MyClass>(1);
    }
```

`explicit` keyword is always to be used to prevent implicit conversion for a constructor and it applies to constructor in a class declaration.

Comment: The third constructor in the first example isn't a copy constructor. A copy constructors argument has to be one of: `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&`, or `const volatile X&`.

Comment: You can just write `MyClass M(1);` etc. in the last example. Careful with those multicharacter literals as well.

Comment: Did you even bother compiling the code before posting it? Your *strings* are actually multicharacter constants, and do not implicitly convert to `char const *`!

Comment: I also don't think that a constructor needs to have one argument to be a *converting constructor*. It just needs to be non-explicit: "A constructor declared without the *function-specifier* `explicit` specifies a conversion from the types of its parameters to the type of its class. Such a constructor is called a *converting constructor*."

Comment: Actually, in C++03 it must have a single parameter. In C++11 it can have any amount. This is to make room for conversions from a *braced-init-list*.

Comment: "A constructor that can be called with a single argument is used for conversions from the type of the argument to the class type. Such a constructor is called a conversion constructor." comes from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2ff0fz8(v=vs.80).aspx. OK for difference C++03 / C++11

Comment: @MooingDuck It says "can be called with a single parameter" - basically the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for not writing, as so many on the web have done, "Easy: implicit conversions don't use the keyword explicit" and then dusting your hands with the satisfaction of a job well done.  Regardless of the faults others have complained of, this answer is straightforward without being self-referential.

Answer (score 3):

A conversion constructor is a single-parameter constructor that is declared without the function specifier explicit . The compiler uses conversion constructors to convert objects from the type of the first parameter to the type of the conversion constructor's class.