# function Pointer Return

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

i'v got 3 question in this code:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
class BST
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        T data;
        Node * left, * right;

        Node () : data (), left (nullptr), right (nullptr) {}
        Node (T const & v, Node * left_, Node * right_) : data (v), left (left_), right (right_) {}
    };

public:
    class Iterator
    {
        friend class BST;

    private:
        Iterator ();
        explicit Iterator (Node * node);

    public:
    };

public:
    BST ()
        : m_root (nullptr)
    {}

    ~BST ()
    {
        clear ();
    }

    void clear ()
    {
        clear (m_root);
    }

    Iterator insert (T const & v)
    {
        Node * p = new Node (v, nullptr, nullptr);

        if (nullptr == m_root)
            m_root = p;
        else
            insert (m_root, p);

        return Iterator(p);
    }

    Iterator find (T const & v) const
    {
        Node * p = find (m_root, v);
        if (nullptr != p)
            return Iterator(p);
        else
            Iterator();
    }

    int size () const
    {
        return size(m_root);
    }

    int height () const
    {
        return height(m_root);
    }

    // For Sunday, 1392/11/27 23:59
    int depth (Iterator it) const;  // <---
    bool erase (T const & v);       // <---
    bool erase (Iterator it);       // <---
    void printInfix () const;       // <---
    void printPrefix () const;      // <---

private:
    void clear (Node * root)
    {
        if (nullptr == root)
            return;
        clear (root->left);
        clear (root->right);
        delete root;
    }

    void insert (Node * root, Node * node)
    {
        assert (root != nullptr);
        assert (node != nullptr);

        if (node->data < root->data)
            if (nullptr != root->left)
                insert (root->left, node);
            else
                root->left = node;
        else
            if (nullptr != root->right)
                insert (root->right, node);
            else
                root->right = node;
    }

    Node * find (Node * root, T const & v) const
    {
        if (nullptr == root)
            return nullptr;

        if (v < root->data)
            return find(root->left, v);
        else if (root->data < v)
            return find(root->right, v);
        else    // Eureka!
            return root;
    }

    int size (Node * root) const
    {
        if (nullptr == root) return 0;
        return 1 + size(root->left) + size(root->right);
    }

    int height (Node * root) const
    {
        if (nullptr == root) return 0;
        return 1 + std::max(height(root->left), height(root->right));
    }

private:
    Node * m_root;
};
```

what is Iterator actually do and why we use it?

what is explicit and what does it do?

and the important one : why we return for example "Node *" from a function? how we can use it? and how this work in this code?

thanks so much...!

Comment: `explicit` avoids implicit conversions, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077466/what-is-a-converting-constructor-in-c-what-is-it-for

Comment: Have you tried googling on bing for the first two questions, since you'll get all the answers!

Comment: yeah sure! but my important question is the last one! any suggestion?!

Comment: Do you understand anything about the code? Because if you don't know yet what Node* is then you need to step back and master the basic types in use. Or is it that you don't understand function return values?

Comment: i just want to know why we use Node * instead of Node ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I will answer to your last question:

> why we return for example "Node *" from a function? how we can use it?
>   and how this work in this code?

`Node*` means 'pointer to Node'. We return Node*, because Node itself is stored somewhere 'inside' the BST. When you say 'find me a node with value = 5', you don't want to create a new Node, do you? You want the BST to find existing Node with such value inside the tree and then return **pointer to it**, so you can operate on it directly. If return type was declared as `Node`, new Node would be created each time, so operating on returned object would not change state of original Node stored inside the tree.

There is also one reason to declare function as returning Node* - in this case, function can return NULL (which means 'zero', 'none', 'pointer to nothing') and signal by this that required value is not present in tree. With Node, function would have to always return an object and you would need to have a way to check if it's a valid object or not.

Returned pointer can be used this way:

```
Node* node = bst.find(5);
std::cout<<"Node value: "<<*node;
*node = 10;
std::cout<<"Node value after change: "<<*node;
```

If you are not familiar with pointers, you should check this:
http://alumni.cs.ucr.edu/~pdiloren/C++_Pointers/
http://www.howtoforge.com/pointers_c_plusplus

Now, about iterators:

[Iterator](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/STL#Iterators) in terms of C++ can be simply described as a 'object used to iterate over collection of elements'. The most simple collection is an array defined this way:

```
int table[100]
```

This is collection of 100 ints. You can iterate over them using a pointer like this:

```
int* table_iter = table; //or: int* table_iter = &table[0]
int index = 0;
while(index < 100)
{
  *table_iter = 10; //Set value of number currently pointed by iterator
  ++table_iter; //Move iterator to next element
}
```

Of course I named my pointer `table_iter`, but it's normal, common, standard pointer. But this kind of iteration could be also done without pointer. For example:

```
for(int index = 0; index < 100; ++index)
{
  table[index] = 10;
}
```

We prefer first solution, because element accessing always involve offset computing. That means, that in order to know where `table[index]` is, program must take address of `table` and then add to this value size of `table`'s type multiplied by `index`. Of course, there are some optimizations that can be performed in such simple `for`s as the above, but I'm talking here about very general case. In case of iterator, all we do is simple 'increment by one', which, in case pointers, means moving pointer by one element of pointer's type.

Now, there is also one reason why we prefer first notation - the same reason that stands behind iterators - because it's generic notation. What does it mean? It means that in first sample we say something like this:

- Set **pointer** to first element.
- Until there are still elements behind current position:
- Do something with this element
- Set **pointer** to next element in collection.

I marked **pointer** because that's exactly what iterator is - a pointer that points to some element in collection.

Now, let's look very carefully at `for()` version. It says:

- For `n` = 0....99
- Do something with element at `table[n]`

Do you see the difference? Iterator itself doesn't assume anything about collection it can iterate through. It is something than we cold generally call `for each`. And that's why they were introduced - they hide the details behind **internals of iteration itself**. Think about that - how would you use pointer to go through binary tree? Hash map? Octree? When using iterators, code will always look almost identically:

```
Collection<int> ints;
ints.add(5); //add() is a memeber function that adds new element to collection.
ints.add(6);
//... etc
Collection::Iterator iter = ints.begin(); //Set `iter` to the beginning of out collection.
while(iter != ints.end()) //While there are still elements...
{
  *iter = *iter * 2; //Multiply every int by 2 and save it.
}
```

The important thing is, that in above code `Collection` could be anything - List, Vector, BST, HashMap, Octree... Iterators hide iteration details from us.

It's also quite obvious, that iterators for different collections are implemented in different way - they internally store required informations (pointers, offsets, positions) required for proper working, but from user's point of view they are simple 'pointers' that can be moved forward/backward to go through elements.

Also, you should understand, that Iterator is not a type in general - it's a concept, abstraction layer, that hides some implementation details of a particular task (iteration in this case). `std::vector<int>::iterator` is a concrete type, same goes for `std::multimap<int, std::string>::iterator`. But 'Iterator' is present in many modern programming languages, when they can exist under different names.