# Operator overloading error "binary '+' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand"

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading

```
class CFruit { 
private: 
 string m_name; 
public: 

 string getName() const; 

 CFruit(string name = "NoName"); 
};
```

The fruitsalad is represented in the class CFruitSalad:

```
class CFruitSalad { 
//Overloaded Operators 
friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const CFruitSalad& f); 
friend CFruitSalad operator +(const CFruit& f1, const CFruit& f2); 

private: 
 string m_fruitsalad; 
public: 

 CFruitSalad(string content = ""); 
 string getName() const; 
};
```

Now when I use write this:

```
 CFruit f1("Apple"); 
 CFruit f2("Orange"); 
 CFruit f3 ("Banana"); 
 CFruitSalad fs; 
 fs = f1 + f2 + f3; //this line generates the error 
 cout << "Content: " << fs << endl;
```

When compiled the program the following error is received: 
error C2678: binary '+' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'CFruitSalad' 
(or there is no acceptable conversion)

Why does this error occur and how to solve it?

Comment: Change the type of the first parameter from `CFruit` to `CFruitSalad`.

Answer (score 1):

```
  fs = f1 + f2 + f3;
```

No matter the order of evaluation (assume `f2+ f3` is evaluated at first), it will first return a object of `CFruitSalad` based on your declaration here:

```
friend CFruitSalad operator +(const CFruit& f1, const CFruit& f2);
```

Now, for the next `+` operation, you are adding an object of `CFruit` with an object of `CFruitSalad`, you don't have an overloaded version that takes one `CFruit` and one `CFruitSalad`, which causes the error.

You need to change the implementation of the overloaded `operator+` (Don't overload operators if it is not really meaningful IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

Your `+` operator is only defined between two instances of class `CFruit`. You need to either add another `operator +` for `CFruitSalad` and `CFruit`, or use a [*converting constructor*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077466/what-is-a-converting-constructor-in-c-what-is-it-for) (see the checked answer).

Answer (score 0):

`fs = f1 + f2 + f3; //this line generates the error`

Okay, so order of operations time.

`f1 + f2` calls operator+ and returns a `CFruitSalad` object, which we will call `_f4`.

Then `_f4 + f3` happens, which is trying to call `operator+ (CFruitSalad const &, CFruit const &)`, causing your error.

Answer (score 0):

You defined operator + as

```
friend CFruitSalad operator +(const CFruit& f1, const CFruit& f2);
```

that is as having return type **CFruitSalad**

Binary operator + is evaluared left to right. So in this statement

```
fs = f1 + f2 + f3;
```

after evaluating `f1 + f2` you get a temporary object of type **CFruitSalad** and try to add it with object f3 that has type **CFruit**. However you did not define operator + that has the left operand of type **CFruitSalad** and the right operand of type **CFruit** and there is no conversion function that could convert an object of one type to another.

So the compiler issues the error.

You could declare the operator as

```
friend CFruitSalad operator +(const CFruitSalad& f1, const CFruit& f2);
```

Or could make it a member function of class CFruitSalad. For example

```
CFruitSalad operator +( const CFruit& f2) const;
```

Also there would be a sense to declare `operator +=` instead of the operator + For example

```
CFruitSalad & operator +=( const CFruit& f2);
```