# what is the return type of the new operator in c++ & why can we assign the returned value to a variable(non-pointer)?

Tags: c++

I know that the new operator in c++ always return a pointer to the created object.

```
class Node {
    int data;
    Node* next;
    public:
        Node();//default 
        Node(int);//parameter
        Node(int, Node*);//parameter2
        Node(Node*);//copy
        ~Node();
        void setData(int);
        void setNext(Node*);
        int getData();
        Node* getNext();
        void display();
};
```

So that we can do:

```
Node *n = new Node;
```

However, I also saw the following code:

```
Node n2 = new Node;
```

I tested it myself and I works as well.

What is the reason for this ?

Comment: Time to kill that compiler if second case works!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please for the second.

Comment: What's a `Node`? Is there an implicit conversion defined from pointer types to `Node`?

Comment: @billz The compiler is actually provided default by Ubuntu.

Comment: You probably forgot to enable warnings when you compiled.

Comment: What warnings? `Node*` is not convertible to `Node`. To have that compile correctly, he'd need to provide some implicit conversion path between the types..

Comment: @user2357112  I just posted the class's header file. Is that because I provided the copy constructor?

Comment: What you call *copy constructor* is in fact a *conversion constructor*. The copy c'tor signature is `Node(const Node&)`.

Comment: This is only possible when class has copy constructor. And that's anyway not a good thing to do, because object created with `new` (and copied to n2) will remain in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Node(Node*);//copy
```

This is NOT a copy constructor and is an implicit conversion from Node* to Node.

The correct prototype for a copy constructor is:

```
Node(Node const&);
```

For those of you who like to get riled up about coding style then this is also the same thing:

```
Node(const Node&);
```

If you need a copy constructor then it is very likely that you will also require an assignment operator:

```
Node& operator=(Node const&);
```

If you have a constructor that accepts a pointer of the same type, it is much safer to make that constructor explicit:

```
explicit Node(Node*);
```

This would have trapped your assignment from a pointer to a value type at compile time and possibly prevented the ensuing memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

`Node(Node*);//copy` isn't a proper copy constructor. A normal copy constructor takes it argument by const reference, i.e. `Node(Node const& src)`.

Still, `` `Node(Node*) `` exists, and when you initialize `Node n2` with a `Node*` from `new Node` it's the constructor chosen. It's a perfect match.

If you're working with `new` and raw pointers (i.e. not `std::unique_ptr<Node>`), watch out for memory leaks. Certainly your public interface should not expose `Node*`.

Comment: Re "isn't a proper copy constructor", note also that `Node(int)` isn't a proper constructor. And so on, e.g. `Node()` isn't a proper copy constructor. I think you've misinterpreted the short comment "copy" in the code: presumably it refers to a ~cloning operation, and is not a claim that the constructor is a copy constructor.

Comment: The constructor marked "default" is in fact a proper _default constructor_ so it's reasonable to assume that standard terminology was intended.

Comment: with standard terminology it's unreasonable to assume that the word "copy" means "copy constructor". [`copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) is something else. however, my point was that that misleading assumption is unreasonable even without an artificial support scaffolding such as "standard terminology".

Comment: And `default` is a label in `switch`. Read the bloody question, they're comments on the different constructors.

Comment: your swearing indicates that your own view of your assumptions is that they don't hold.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic memory is allocated using operator new.

```
Node *n= new Node;
```

allocates space for a single element of type `Node` and returns a *pointer* to it.

> Node n2=new Node;

works in this case due to `Node()` and `Node(Node*)` functions.

`Node(Node*)` is doing the implicit conversion from `Node*` to Node in this case as the assignment is doing

> new Node => Node(new Node) => Node(Node*)

Answer (score 1):

It **might** work **only** because you have created a really unusual copy constructor:

```
Node(Node*); //copy
```

It takes **a pointer** and creates an object from it. Therefore, your line

```
Node n2 = new Node;
```

in fact is a:

```
Node n2 = Node( new Node() );
```

Observe the "new Node" returning pointer, and a object constructor `Node()`. I think that copy constructor would need to be implicit though, but that's another case.

It is an unusual copy-ctor, because copy-ctors **usually** doesn't take pointer, and they do that for this very reason: it makes too easy to make stupid errors and typos like forgetting a `*` after the type. Usually, they take const-reference to the copied object:

```
Node(Node const&); //copy
```

Having it this way, the line

```
Node n2 = new Node;
```

would not compile, as there'd be no way to "convert" `Node*` to `Node`. On the other hand, if you really wanted to have that line working again, you'd need to write:

```
Node n2 = *(new Node);
```

or something similar. Still, it's a bad idea, since the recently `new`-ed object will never be deleted and will linger in the memory forever (that is, until program exists).

To get that cleaned up:

```
Node* tmp = new Node;
Node n2 = Node(*tmp);
delete tmp;
```

but this is approaching a nonsese anyways, since you create a new obejct just to create a new object. This horrible thing should be probably rewritten as simple:

```
Node n2 = Node();
```

EDIT: which of course is the same as plain

```
Node n2;
```

unless your compiler is real issues :)

Comment: I disagree with your last line. Why should it not be written as `Node n2;`?

Comment: @BartvanNierop: Yes, it could be written in short form, but I wanted to emphasise the 'construction' part.

Answer (score 0):

By defining suitable constructors instances of a type can be initialized with just about anything as constructor argument.

In addition, since there is conversion from any raw pointer type to `bool`, you can also do

```
bool x = new Node;
```

And the language allows much else that might appear baffling at first, e.g.

```
Node n = n;
```

The idea is that a C++ programmer prefers having control over being nannied. So in C++ what isn't explicitly forbidden is usually allowed, because in *some* context it might make sense and be useful. Some other languages are based on different philosophies.

---

It can often (but not always) be a good idea to declare a constructor with a single argument as **`explicit`**. Then it will not be implicitly invoked. E.g.,

```
explicit Node( Node* );
```

Then the declaration

```
Node n = new Node();
```

will result in a compilation error.

However, explicit use of that constructor, as in

```
Node n( new Node() );
```

will still compile.

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong copy constructor:

```
Node(Node*);//copy
```

This actually is an implicit conversion from `Node*` to `Node`, definitely not what you want.
Copy constructor by definition should allow `const Node&` in parameter, e.g.:

```
Node( const Node& );
```

Please see [Copy constructors, assignment operators, and exception safe assignment](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/):

> Note that none of the following constructors, despite the fact that
>   they could do the same thing as a copy constructor, are copy
>   constructors:
>
> ```
> MyClass( MyClass* other );
> MyClass( const MyClass* other );
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your comments help me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of implicit constructor conversion.

In this case :

```
Node n = new Node;
```

Your `Node (Node *);` constructor will be implicitly called.

A more complete explanation [can be found here for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15077788/3460805).

You can prevent this from happening by flagging this constructor with they explicit keyword :

```
explicit Node (Node *);
```

And now above code won't compile (g++ 4.7.2) :

> error: conversion from ‘Node*’ to non-scalar type ‘Node’ requested

You'll have to explicitly call the constructor :

```
Node n (new Node);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works because your Node class defines a constructor which takes a Node pointer. It is this one:

```
Node(Node*);//copy
```

This isn't the correct syntax for a copy constructor by the way, which would be:

```
Node(const Node& other);
```

When you assign the `new Node` to a node object with `Node n2 = new Node;` you are (1) allocating a new Node object on the heap, (2) initialising n2 on the stack by calling the constructor which takes a Node pointer and (3) leaking the heap-allocated Node.