# Converting (implicit) boost shared_ptr<T> to shared_ptr<const T>

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I have a C++ function that takes as arguments something like:

```
void myFunction(shared_ptr<const MyObject> ptr)) {
    ...
}
```

and in my main code I do something like this, and it compiles:

```
shared_ptr<MyObject> test(new MyObject());
myFunction(test);
```

Does this mean that inside MyFunction, if I dereference ptr, then the object is constant and cannot be modified?

What are the conversions going on to allow this to compile?

Comment: [There's a constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)

Answer (score 1):

It uses the following constructor of `std::shared_ptr`:

```
template<class Y> shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<Y>& r) noexcept;
```

Which is defined to "not participate in the overload resolution unless `Y*` is implicitly
convertible to `T*`". Since, in your example, `T*` is implicitly convertible to `const T*`, everything is fine. This is nice, of course, because it means that `shared_ptr`s behave just like raw pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The code compiles because there is a constructor of `shared_ptr<const MyObject>` that takes a `shared_ptr<MyObject>` (shown in Joseph Mansfield's answer), since a `const MyObject` can be bound without issue to a `MyObject` (see [What is a converting constructor in C++ ? What is it for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077466/what-is-a-converting-constructor-in-c-what-is-it-for) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2ff0fz8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)). Indeed, if you try to modify the value pointed to by `ptr` in `myFunction`, then you will get compilation errors indicating that you are trying to modify a constant object.

Comment: How would it construct from a raw pointer when you pass a `shared_ptr`?

Comment: Sorry, it wouldn't. I just saw that you were passing a shared_ptr, edited.