# Pass opencv inputarray and use it as std::vector

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I want write a customized function which use the cv::InputArray as parameters.
Within the function, I understand I can use cv::InputArray::getMat to obtain a header of the input cv::Mat.

I have some confusions while passing std::vector to the cv::InputArray.

1.If I pass std::vector into a function, can I still get the std::vector in the function? For example:

```
void foo(cv::InputArray _input)
{
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> input = _input.getVector() // getVector function doesn't exist
}

std::vector<cv::Point2f> a;
foo(a);
```

2.If I pass std::vector to the function and use the getMat to get a cv::Mat within the function, how the mat will looks like?

Poly has made a clear explanation in case of `std::vector<char>`. What if I want to get `std::vector<cv::Point2f>` in the function, any suggestions?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass vector to the function which takes `InputArray`, you implicitly call converting constructor `InputArray::InputArray(vector)`. (Converting constructor is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15077788/928387)

In this constructor, the vector's pointer is simply assigned to `obj` member variable in InputArray. If you use OpenCV 3.0, InputArray has getObj() method, so you can get vector by the following way:

```
// Only works on OpenCV 3.0 or above
const std::vector<Point2f>& input = *(const std::vector<Point2f>*)_input.getObj();
```

If you use OpenCV 2.X, you can use `InputArray::getMat()`. It returns `Mat` object that has a pointer to the data. So you can do the following way as well.

```
// Should Work on any OpenCV version
cv::Mat mat = _input.getMat();
Point2f *data = (Point2f *)mat.data;
int length = mat.total();
std::vector<Point2f> input;
input.assign(data, data + length);
```

Regarding your second question, if you call `InputArray::getMat()` on InputArray object with N element, it returns (N*1) matrix.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I tried both ways but neither of them worked. For the first way, the InputArray doesn't have getObj() method so I assume you mean getMat(). This give me compilation error like: cannot convert from 'cv::Mat' to 'const std::vector<_Ty> *'. For the second way, I want to recover vector of cv::Point2f, but the results were not correct.

Comment: Seems like only OpenCV 3.0 has getObj() method. I update my original answer to include version description and use Point2f. I successfully recover vector<Point2f> on my machine using OpenCV 2.4.8. Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that [`InputArray::getObj()`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d32/classcv_1_1__InputArray.html#aa33a71040201aa69ac880bdcd1d92541) returns the object by whom it was created. So casting **only** works, if `_input` was created using a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)! This can be checked via [`InputArray::isVector()`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d32/classcv_1_1__InputArray.html#ad9a833a610fa8a02d1f840bd6f213086).

Otherwise, a new [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) object must be created. Unfortunately, there is no way to tell [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to use existing data. I think it is not even possible when using your own [allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator). If you still want a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), use pointers/iterators (either in [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) or in [`std::vector::assign()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign)) to create a new object with a copy of the data. You can obtain the size directly from `_input` via [`InputArray::total()`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d32/classcv_1_1__InputArray.html#aad62862c81d1d5bdf3f6597a32585844).

#### Vector

Based on the previous observations, I combined the attempts proposed by [Poly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/928387/poly).

```
std::vector<Point2f> *input;
if (_input.isVector()) {
    input = static_cast<std::vector<Point2f>*>(_input.getObj());
} else {
    size_t length = _input.total();
    Point2f* data = reinterpret_cast<Point2f*>(_input.getMat().data);
    input = new std::vector<Point2f>(data, data + length);
}
```

#### Template

To reuse code for other types, I recommend using templates.

```
template<class T>
std::vector<T>& getVec(InputArray _input) {
    std::vector<T> *input;
    if (_input.isVector()) {
        input = static_cast<std::vector<T>*>(_input.getObj());
    } else {
        size_t length = _input.total();
        T* data = reinterpret_cast<T*>(_input.getMat().data);
        input = new std::vector<T>(data, data + length);
    }
    return *input;
}
```

Further, you should check if types are compatible via [`InputArray::type()`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d32/classcv_1_1__InputArray.html#aad62862c81d1d5bdf3f6597a32585844).

#### Arrays

If you just want easy indexing, you could of course use standard C-style arrays (**Note** that C++-style [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) also needs to copy data).

```
Point2f* data = reinterpret_cast<Point2f*>(_input.getMat().data);
```

Then you can access data via

```
Point2f p = data[5];
```