# Does this constructor call have a special name?

Tags: c++

Assume you have two classes A and , B has a constructor from A : B(A a).

Assume you have a non overloaded function f that takes an B object as a parameter : void f(B b)
If I write f(a) the compiler will automatically call the B constructor from A. What is this called ?

Comment: Implicit conversion?

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean a [*converting constructor*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15077788/2030653).

Comment: Good job finding the duplicate.