# How to define an implicit conversion from double?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have defined a class `Complex` which overloads the `+` operator:

```
Complex operator+(Complex const& x, Complex const& y);
```

I want to define an implicit conversion from `double` to `Complex`, such that, for example, if I write `c + d`, where `c` is a `Complex` and `d` a `double`, it will call my overloaded `+` that I defined above and return a `Complex`. How can I do this?

Comment: @DavidHammen typo corrected. Thanks.

Comment: have a look at std::complex (it has the conversion, already)

Comment: @DieterLücking `Complex` was just an example. I wanted to understand how to write the implicit conversion in general.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to define a constructor for it. This is referred to as a ["converting constructor"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077466/what-is-a-converting-constructor-in-c-what-is-it-for)

```
Complex::Complex(double x)
{
    // do conversion
}
```

This will allow for implicit conversion, as long as you don't use the `explicit` keyword, which will force you to have to use a cast to convert.

You can also define other versions of your `operator+`

```
Complex operator+(Complex const& x, double y);
Complex operator+(double x, Complex const& y);
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply add a non-`explicit` constructor for `Complex` taking a `double` :

```
Complex(double value);
```

The compiler will automatically use it to implicitly convert a `double` to `Complex`.