# C++ thread with a recursive function

Tags: c++, xcode, multithreading, recursion

```
void merge_sort_thread(vector<int>& array) {
if (1 < array.size()) {
    vector<int> array1(array.begin(), array.begin() + array.size() / 2);
    thread first= thread(merge_sort_thread,array1);

    vector<int> array2(array.begin() + array.size() / 2, array.end());
    thread second = thread(merge_sort_thread,array2);
    first.join(); //wait for both ended
    second.join();
    merge (array1.begin(),array1.end(),array2.begin(),array2.end(),array.begin());
}
```

I am using Xcode to build and run, and it is a build failure.
With prompt:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/thread:332:5:
>   Attempt to use a deleted function

I know threading here is not efficient, but I want to know why this not work.

Comment: You can't copy a thread. Just create one instead of creating one and copying it: `thread first(merge_sort_thread, array1);`.

Comment: It's probably not a very good idea, to create a new thread on every recursion.

Comment: Actually I tried both, and result is the same @molbdnilo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::thread` deduces the type of bound arguments and stores a copy of them in the thread object. In your case the the argument is deduced to be a reference. However references, as you know, cannot be copied. If you want to pass a reference to a function inside `std::thread`, then you can use `std::ref` which creates a reference wrapper that is copyable:

```
thread first(merge_sort_thread,std::ref(array1));
```

Comment: @L.Y there's no comment so the downvoter probably didn't have a good reason for it. It was possibly done at random or by accident. Feel free to upvote if the answer is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing `copy initialization` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132268/explicit-and-non-explicit-constructors/32132480#32132480)), and threads are *not* allowed to be copyable objects for obvious reasons.

Instead, replace this kind of code

```
 thread foo = thread(...);
```

With this

```
thread foo(...);
```

Or, if you don't have phobias (like me...) to ugly code, and you believe in the promises of the 11th C++...

```
thread foo{...};
```

Comment: He's copy initializing with an rvalue and threads *are* movable. It's not a good way to initialize the thread but it should compile, shouldn't it?

Comment: Actually I tried both, and result is the same @KemyLand Any other suggestion?

Comment: @L.Y: Well, this is no longer standard-obeying behaviour. Are you sure your XCode installation is correct? Are you compiling in C++11 mode?