# Is there an umbrella term to group the "from-scratch" constructors, distinguishing them from the copy and move constructors?

Tags: c++, c++11, terminology

This one is a jargon question.
There are several umbrella terms to group logical operations in C++. For example:

- for the destructor, copy/move assignment and constructors: the **copy control** operations.

Is there one term for all constructors that create an object without copying or moving from another object of the same class ?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily call the copy constructor as not "from scratch" when it comes to things like object slicing. Therefore I would not have thought that such a term exists. Good question though.

Comment: @Bathsheba Perhaps I missunderstood your comment, but I would **not** either call the copy constructor "from scratch", quite the opposite (even if it is technically creating another instance totally separated from the first one). I just sometime find myself willing to refer to the group of of all constructors except copy and move.

Comment: Sorry, missed out a not. What I was trying to say is that I believe any distinction would be too blurred for it to be meaningful.

Comment: @Bathsheba You could easily be right! This distinction can be useful in some specific cases, but it does not mean that it can be applied widely enough to have a 'standard' name. Let this question be a probe ;)

Comment: We have [**direct initialization**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), when you, _e.g._, construct an object using a set of (non-self) arguments.

Comment: The standard uses the phrase "copy/move constructor" to (trivally) group the copy and move constructors, so "non-copy/move constructor" is probably the best you can do.

Comment: @VaughnCato Yes, if you want a name for "everything except what is describe by term X", "not term X" is sort of obvious.  Lacking a *reason* to talk about them as a group, it is probably also optimal.  AdN: Why do you want this term?

Comment: I wanted this term because, in our current project, we have a logic distinction between the "non-copy/move" ctors, that make a new object and add it to a registry, and the copy/move ctors, that behave a bit differently. I was wondering if there was a standard way to refer to those, more out of curiosity than anything else. As **VaughnCato** pointer out, the negation works for practical purposes ;)

Answer (score 0):

No.

You also have "default constructor" and ["converting constructor"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077466/what-is-a-converting-constructor-in-c-what-is-it-for), but I don't think they have a common term describing them all.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Both of them would be under this same group missing a name.