# C++ default assignment operator from different type

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators

I have the following class as a wrapper around the basic type `bool`:

```
class MyBoolean {
public:
    MyBoolean(bool value = false):value(value) {};
    virtual ~MyBoolean() {};

    void MySpecialFunction();
    ...

private:
    bool value;
}
```

I want to use `MyBoolean` in expressions as normal `bool`. That is, assign to it, compare, etc. For that I define the assignment and implicit type cast operators.

```
inline operator bool() const {
    return value;
}
inline bool operator = (const bool &rhs) {
    return value = rhs;
}
```

It seems however that the assignment operator is not needed. The following code compiles just with type cast operator, without the assignment operator:

```
MyBoolean b;
b = true;
```

Why doesn't the compiler complain it cannot assign `bool` into `MyBoolean`? What is the default implementation of the assignment operator from a different type in C++?

Comment: Smart compilers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a converting constructor in C++ ? What is it for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077466/what-is-a-converting-constructor-in-c-what-is-it-for)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that explains it! A related question then: what is the most efficient implementation, i.e. adding the least overhead. Shall I overload all the necessary operators (=, ==, !=, !, &&, ||)? Or is this minimalistic approach good enough?

Comment: @DimChtz No, not "smart compilers" but "language rules" (in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you do not need the assignment operator is because you have a non-explicit [converting constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor).  When you do

```
b = true;
```

The compiler sees that it can convert `true` to a `MyBoolean` using

```
MyBoolean(bool value = false):value(value) {};
```

Since you get one user provided conversion the compiler constructs a temporary `MyBoolean` and then assigns that to `b` using the default copy assignment operator.

Comment: Does the converting constructor create more overhead than if the assignment operator is defined and used?

Comment: @Brain Yes,  you construct a temporary.  If you had a assignment operator that took a `bool` no temporary would need to be created.

Answer (score 3):

You constructor `MyBoolean(bool value = false)` is a "[converting constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor)" and the compiler is allowed to use such a one to generate *one* implicit conversion (in this case from `bool` to `MyBoolean`).

If you do not want the constructor to be used for implicit conversions then declare it as `explicit` - as in

```
explicit MyBoolean(bool value = false)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `b = true` it makes a new `MyBoolean`.

```
MyBoolean b;
b = true;
```

Evaluates to

```
MyBoolean b;
b = MyBoolean(true);
```

This is called [implicit type conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion)