# Convert string to custom class

Tags: c++

Is there a way to convert a string to a custom class, for example if I have a class named Numb, but I want to declared it as a string with the = operator, can I overload it?

```
class Numb{
      std::string x;
};

int main(){
    Numb n = "32";
   //Creates a Numb and makes x = "32"
}
```

Comment: One way to do this is to add a constructor for `Numb`, so that you initialize the variable as `Numb n("32");`

Comment: No , I don't want a constructor

Comment: Another way is to overload the assignment operator. So the answer to your original question is yes, you can overload it. There are many examples online on how to do so if you don't know the format.

Comment: "No , I don't want a constructor" your class has a constructor anyhow, why dont you want to use it?

Comment: Recommended reading: [What is a converting constructor in C++ ? What is it for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077466/what-is-a-converting-constructor-in-c-what-is-it-for)

Comment: @polmonroig "*No , I don't want a constructor*" - yes, you do. `Numb n = "32";` is identical to `Numb n("32");` They are both calls to the same constructor. So you would have to give `Numb` a constructor that accepts a `const char*` or a `std::string` as input, and then the constructor can assign that value to your `x` member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to construct Numbs from a string literal. <s>String literals are indistinguishable from type `const char *`</s> String literals have type `const char [N]`, which we can take as an argument by writing a function that accepts `const char *`.

To define a converting constructor with this behavior, just write a signature like that of a copy constructor, but instead of expecting an argument of the same type, expect an argument of type `const char *`. Its signature would look like `Myclass(const char *);`

Alternatively, you can copy or move construct from strings, but that would require doing `Numb n = std::string { "32" };` or similar, to convert the string constant to a std::string.

Here is some sample code, in which main() returns 3. Here we also demonstrate what to do with the value: if we instead did `Num n2 = std::string { "TRAP" };`, the code would return 1. If we did `Num n2 = std::string { "ANYTHING OTHER THAN TRAP" };` it would return 2.

```
#include <string>

struct Num {
    Num()
      : _val(2) {}

    Num(const std::string & str) {
        if (str == "TRAP") {
            _val = 1;
        } else {
            _val = 2;
        }
    }

    Num(const char * s) {
        _val = 3;
    }

    int _val;    
};

int main(void) {
    // Num n = std::string { "TRAP" }; // returns 1
    // Num n = std::string { "NOTTRAP" }; // returns 2
    Num n = "TRAP";
    return n._val;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/g/Lqwdiw

EDIT: Fix a mistake re the type system, take the string arg as & not &&, simplify example, update compiler explorer link.

Comment: "String literals are indistinguishable from type `const char *`", well, not exactly. The type of a string literal is `const char [N]`, where `N` is the length of the string + 1 for the null terminator. So you *can* distinguish it from a `const char *`, but a `const char *` parameter can accept string literals

Comment: Sorry, I meant as the argument to a function; or am I mistaken, and there's a way to write a function that takes `const char [N]` as an argument and not `const char *`?

Comment: `const std::string&&`?  A const r-value reference doesn't make sense

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can using [converting constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor). Something like:

```
struct A {
  A(std::string);
  // A is a struct, so str is public
  std::string str;
};

// implementation for converting constructor
A::A(std::string s) {
  str = s;
}

int main() {
  A my_a = std::string("hello");
  std::cout << my_a.str << '\n';
}
```

Sometimes you might not want this behavior. You can mark the constructor as `explicit` to disable it.

Comment: That seems to work, but how can I access the string "hello" after initializing?

Comment: @polmonroig Depends on your class. Maybe you expose your string as a public member? Maybe you create a getter? Maybe you overload `operator<<`?

Comment: but I mean, where is the string stored, you only declared a constructor,

Comment: @polmonroig i'll add to my answer

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, it is just what I wanted, thanks

Comment: You should change the constructor to accept the `std::string` by `const` reference, and get rid of the explicit conversion to `std::string` when passing in a string literal: `struct A { A(const std::string &); std::string str; }; ... A::A(const std::string &s) : str(s) {} ... A my_a = "hello";`

Answer (score 1):

If you make `x` a `public` member, you can assign to it like this:

```
class Numb
{
    public:
        std::string x;
};

int main()
{
    Numb n{ "32" };
    Numb o = { "33" };
    n = { "34" };
    o.x = "35";
}
```