# The proper name for the following class relationship

Tags: c++, oop

There are two classes:

```
Class A{
private:
  int data;
public:
  A(B b) {data=b.do_something()}
};
```

and

```
Class B{
public:
  int do.something(){.....};
};
```

An object of `Class B` helps to make some job to `Class A` in the constructor or, alternatively, as a local variable in methods. Objects of `Class B` are never `Class A` members. How to call such kind of relationship? That is neither Association, nor Aggregation, nor Composition as far as I understand.

Comment: `A` uses `B` or, in your specific case, `A` is constructed using `B`.

Comment: @Peter Is there a common name for such relationship?

Comment: @maksim_volodin it's not a relationship *per se*. See below.

Comment: @TomTrebicky Your answer is about the particular C++ feature. My question is about the relationship classification independently of the language. I put only one parameter in the ctr but it can be more `A(B b, C c.....)` as well there may be methods accepting objects as parameters that do not belong to the class members.

Comment: One name for the relationship is "uses".    In UML it is termed a "Realisation"  (or "realization" for american spellers).     As in, a printer is realised using a printer setup, or (describing the relationship in the opposite sense) a printer setup controls the realisation of a printer.   Technically, it is also viewed as a type of association.

Comment: @maksim_volodin you have to be specific. Yet, the answer still stands, what you showed is a *converting constructor*. There is no other specific name for what you are referring to. Methods changing data members are just that. Or possibly setters.

Comment: @Peter It becomes clear if I use not behaviour(methods) but data(fields) of `class B`, for example `A(B b){data=B.b}` if it is still called realization? I always thought about realization as an interface behaviour implementation, denoted as a dot line on UML diagrams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a relationship is called **Dependency**, see [the link](http://usna86-techbits.blogspot.com/2012/11/uml-class-diagram-relationships.html)

Answer (score 0):

`A (B b) ...` is referred to as a converting constructor. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077466/what-is-a-converting-constructor-in-c-what-is-it-for) out.

Answer (score 0):

One term for the relationship is "uses".   As in "`A` uses `B`" or (more specifically in your example)  "Construction of `A` uses `B`" or "`A` is constructed using `B`".

In UML it is a type of association that is sometimes termed a "Realisation" (or "realization" for american spellers).   In the english language, "realisation" has a number of possible dictionary meanings, but the one relevant here is as a noun "the making or being made real".    As in, "a printer is realised using a printer setup", or "realisation of a printer uses a printer setup", or (describing the relationship in the opposite sense) a "printer setup controls realisation of a printer".