# What is "Unary Constructor"?

Tags: c++, constructor

Here in [this link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Programming_Languages/C%2B%2B/Code/Statements/Variables/Type_Casting#static_cast) it says:

> The static_cast keyword can be used for any normal conversion between
>   types. Conversions that rely on static (compile-time) type
>   information. This includes any casts between numeric types, casts of
>   pointers and references up the hierarchy, conversions with **unary
>   constructor**, conversions with conversion operator. For conversions
>   between numeric types no runtime checks if data fits the new type is
>   performed. Conversion with unary constructor would be performed even
>   if it is declared as explicit.

Also [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/user-defined-conversions-cpp-cli):

> To interoperate well with other CLS-compliant languages, you may wish
>   to wrap each user-defined **unary constructor** for a given class with a
>   corresponding convert-from operator.

What do they mean by "Unary Constructor"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unary means one, so what they are talking about is a constructor with a single parameter.  The standard name for such a thing is a [conversion constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077466/what-is-a-converting-constructor-in-c-what-is-it-for).

Comment: Though the same. You will sometimes hear it in combination with lambdas "unary lambda" function.

Comment: Converting constructors are required to not be explicit, so maybe unary constructor is broader than that.

Comment: @cigien Well in contexts of a static cast, you are being explicit so they still count.

Comment: Extra default parameters would also work for conversion, even if I won't call them unary... But default constructor work the same way (but default doesn't mean zero :) )...

Answer (score 2):

Unary refers to one or singular, so a 'Unary constructor' ideally refers to a constructor with a single parameter.