# Am I correct about how this C++ code works?

Tags: c++

In this code :

```
    class iop {
    public:
        iop(int y) {
            printf("OK\n");
        }

        iop() {
            printf("NO\n");
        }
    };

    int main()
    {
  line 1-   iop o;
  line 2-   o = 8;
  line 3-   return 0;
    }
```

My conclusion of the way this C++ code work with is:

1. Create an object of `iop` class (`o`) using the default parameterless constructor.
2. Create an rvalue object of `iop` class using the constructor with parameter (int) and using the overloaded operator (operator = (iop&&)) to assign it to the object (`o`) then call the destructor of that rvalue.
3. Call the destructor of the object (`o`).

Is my conclusion correct?

Edit
This code also compiled

```
class iop {
public:
    iop(int y) {
        printf("OK\n");
    }

    iop() {
        printf("NO\n");
    }
};

int main()
{
    iop o(5);
    o = 8;
    return 0;
}
output :
OK
OK
```

That is mean two object are created (o) and one is temporary
and the operator= assigen (o) with the temporary object that its constractor argument is 8

Comment: No, it is not correct and a thought experiment should make it obvious that it's not correct. Just focus on `o = 8;` and ask yourself: how is it possible? There is no assignment operator for `=` that takes an `int` parameter, to assign it to `iop`, so how does this compile. You will then reach the conclusion that at least two objects must be constructed here, not one.

Comment: Unrelated, it is called a *destructor*, not distractor. Related, a fine google-fu term right about now would be "converting constructor" . It's important to your conundrum, and is mentioned in several questions on this site, [including this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077466/what-is-a-converting-constructor-in-c-what-is-it-for).

Comment: "using the overloaded operator (operator = (iop&&)) to create an rvalue object" -- this is incorrect. `operator=` does not create anything. This is an assignment operator. It assigns something that was already created, in some form or fashion.

Comment: No, only parameters that get passed by value are effectively copied. Parameters that get passed by reference, by definition, are not copied. This includes rvalue references.

Comment: I edited the post Can you take a look and then tell me if my conclusion is totally correct?
 @Sam Varshavchik

Comment: I thought in this line ( line number two ) o = 8; the temporary object (rvalue) is created by the overloaded operator=(iop&&).but i now know that the temporary object (rvalue) is created in the main function not by the overloaded operator=(iop&&) ( I mean it is created in the scope of main function before calling the overloaded operator(iop&&) ),is this right ? @Sam Varshavchik

Comment: Any object, temporary or not, is always created by a constructor, and not by any other operator. C++ does not work this way. All objects get created by a constructor.

Comment: My two questions are does the temporary object is created in the main function scope ( in my code ) ? and if the overloaded operator takes iop as argument it is mean the operator will call the costructor to create a independent object to the overloaded operator ? @Sam Varshavchik

Comment: At this point, I'd like to introduce you to a debugger. Although the answer to your question is fairly straightforward, there is no reason to ask anyone a question that anyone can answer by themselves. This is exactly what a debugger is for. It runs your program, one line at a time, and shows you what's happening. By running the shown code, one step at a time, it's very easy to see when each constructor gets called, from where, and what gets passed to any class method or overloaded operator. Why don't you try to use a debugger, and see with your own eyes what happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class `iop` has implicitly defined copy and move constructors and assignments.

```
o = 8;
```

This will attempt to call `operator=`. As I've stated the copy and move assignment operators are implicitly defined:

```
iop& operator=(const iop&);
iop& operator=(iop&&);
```

Because `iop` is implicitly constructible from `int`, both operators are viable, but the move one is preferred as is a perfect match.

So yes, a temporary is created from `8`, that is moved into `o`. At the end of the full expression (at `;`) that temporary is destroyed. At the end of `main` scope `o` is destroyed.

So your code is more or less equivalent to `o = iop{8}`.

Sidenote: if you make the int constructor explicit i.e. `explicit iop(int y)` then `o = 8;` will no longer compile.

Comment: So the
iop& operator=(iop&&); is called 
not
 iop& operator=(const iop&);
 ?
@bolov

Comment: @f877576 yes indeed

Comment: I edited the post to answer your Sidenote see the post again 
@bolov

Comment: @f877576 I don't understand. Your edit changes nothing for `o = 8`.

Comment: you said if i make the constructor explicit then o = 8; will no longer compile.
but the code compiles ?
@bolov

Comment: I edited the post one more time see the post again and i am sorry for bothering you @bolov

Comment: I do not understand your sidenote.Can you explain it? and I am sorry for bothering you @bolov

Comment: @f877576 https://godbolt.org/z/oW3necYha and see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-mean

Comment: do you mean add the word explicit to the declaration of the constractor?
@bolov

Comment: @f877576 yes, like in my godbolt example

Comment: I thought in this line ( line number two ) o = 8; the temporary object (rvalue) is created by the overloaded operator=(iop&&).but i now know that the temporary object (rvalue) is created in the main function not by the overloaded operator=(iop&&) ,is this right @bolov ?

Comment: Yes, in the main function. It's not created by the operator or by the main function. It's created by the compiler.

Comment: I mean it is created in the scope of main function before calling the overloaded operator(iop&&),right?@bolov

Comment: @f877576 please consider accepting the answer if it answered your question so that the question doesn't remain unaswered.

Comment: i am so sorry for bothering you but i am a student and i asked this question again ( I mean it is created in the scope of main function before calling the overloaded operator(iop&&),right? ) 
because i need a simple answer (yes or no) to write it in notes  @bolov

Comment: @f877576 as I've said  yes.

Comment: The last thing you said " it is created by the compiler " do you mean ( it is created by the compiler exactly like when i write int v = 9; in the main function the variable that is named v also created by the compiler not by main function ) ? @bolov

Comment: @f877576 yes, the implicit operators/constructors are generated by the compiler. The temporary object is created by the compiler. If you want you can say the temporary object is created by the main function, but at the end of the day it doesn't really matter.

Comment: You wrote in your answer the word " contructible "  What is the meaning of this word ? @bolov

Comment: It meant "constructible" which means "can be constructed". E.g. see [std::is_constructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible)