# Implicit conversion from string type to type of class

Tags: c++, constructor, implicit

```
Constructor that defines the implicit conversion from string type to type
of your class
```

Can someone explain in plain terms what implicit conversion from string type to type
of your class means?

Comment: It probably means a [converting constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077466/what-is-a-converting-constructor-in-c-what-is-it-for).

Answer (score 3):

A *conversion constructor* is basically a constructor that take a single argument of one type (different from the class), and uses it to initialize the object.

Lets say you have the following class:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo() = default;  // Defaulted default constructor

    // Conversion constructor, allows construction from int values
    Foo(int)
    {
    }
};
```

Then you can create `Foo` object with an `int` value:

```
Foo f = 1;  // Equivalent to Foo f = Foo(1)
```

It also allows assignments from `int` values:

```
f = 2;  // Equivalent to f = Foo(2)
```

Comment: Does it have to be struct or can I use it with just regular classes too?

Comment: @00n00r `struct` and `class` are almost exactly the same. The main difference is the default visibility of members, for `class` it's `private` while for `struct` it's `public`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude just to be pedantic, access and visibility are not interchangeable.  Visibility affects name lookup and what goes into an overload set.  Access is a check that happens after overload resolution completes.  Private data and members are visible, but not accessible to outside code, while code that isn't visible isn't even considered.

Comment: The primary difference between struct and class is the default access of struct is public (for members and base classes), while for classes it's private.